# how to hide table when html page opens

Tags: javascript, html

Hallo there
I have some javascript code allowing for a table to be visible when my mouse passes over a link and to hide when my mouse moves out. 
The problem I have is to have the table 'hidden' when the page opens.
How could I achieve this.
This is my code for the hiding and showing of the table.

```
<li  onmouseout="hideMenu('families')" onmouseover="showMenu('families')" ><a href="#">Five Families</a>
                <table class="slideDownOne" id="families" width="120px" border="1px" cellpadding="5px 0px 5px 0px">
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Gambino</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Genovese</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Colombo</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Bonnano</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Luchhese</a></td></tr>
                </table>
            </li>
```

and this is some javascript code i used for the hiding and the showing of the table

```
<script language="javascript">  
        function showMenu(elmnt)
        {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
        }
        function hideMenu(elmnt)
        {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
        }   


    </script>
```

regards
Arian

Comment: Why are you using a table to represent a list?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the text to mouseover in a link but have the mouseovers on the li? Move the mouseover and out to the link or remove it

Answer (score 11):

You need to apply the same CSS you are applying via JavaScript to the table itself:

```
#families { visibility:hidden }
```

or, using inline CSS:

```
<table style="visibility:hidden" class="slideDownOne" id="families" width="120px" border="1px" cellpadding="5px 0px 5px 0px">
...
</table>
```

Note that by using the `visibility` property, the element will still take up space in the document. If you don't want that, you need the `display` property instead:

```
#families { display:none }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `style.display="none"` and `style.display="block"`.

Comment: Assuming he does not want the content to take up the space to stop the page from being reformatted when mousing over the link

Comment: that is mentioned in question? anyway either visibility or display should work on his li, a, or table, but no success he could get.

Comment: He is using visible in the CSS so yes it is mentioned - you are not answering the question at all, just changing the existing code to collapse the html

Comment: actually question title and question code are different contexts. he wants the table to hide in any way

Comment: Same context. Asker simply needs to not show the content per default.

Answer (score 3):

add:

`style="display:none;"`

in table declaration

then in javascript:

```
window.onload = name('families');

function name(form){
    document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li style="visibility:visible;"
```

or make a css file for a class such as

```
.demo
{
visibility:visible;
}

<li class="demo" style="visibility:visible;"
```

Comment: you mean the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to the `<body>` tag of your HTML page: `onload="hideMenu('families')"`

This is a better solution than simply setting the style to be hidden, since for users without JavaScript, this code will never execute so the table will not be hidden.

If you simply set the style to be hidden, the table would be permanently hidden to any users without JavaScript.

Comment: adding inline event handlers is poor practice. Instead us window.onload or attach the events.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  #families{
   visibility:hidden;
  }
  </style>

  <script language="javascript">  
        
        function showMenu(elmnt)
        {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
        }
        function hideMenu(elmnt)
        {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
        }   


    </script>  
 
</head>
<body>
<li  onmouseout="hideMenu('families')" onmouseover="showMenu('families')" ><a href="#">Five Families</a></li> 
    <table class="slideDownOne" id="families" width="120px" border="1px" cellpadding="5px 0px 5px 0px">
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Gambino</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Genovese</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Colombo</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Bonnano</a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">Luchhese</a></td></tr>
                </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```